# Используйте селекторы псевдокласов, чтобы раскрасить ненумерованый список «зеброй»

Tags: html

Используйте селекторы псевдокласов, чтобы раскрасить ненумерованый список «зеброй»

Comment: хорошо, будем использовать

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```css
li:nth-child(2n){
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>
```